# my job disappears without trace

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, qsub

I  am running a weather forecast model and I want to automate the modek runs via crontab. When I submit my job interactive through:

```
qsub -I -l nodes=8:ppn=8 -l walltime=2:00:00
```

The job runs ok.
When I submit through crontab, the job disappears without any trace, no error file any where, no output file, except mail which reads as:

```
From: root@master.cluster (Cron Daemon)
To: test@master.cluster
Subject: Cron <test@master> PATH=/opt/torque/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:. qsub /home/test
/WRF/SCRIPTS/wrf_00_run.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/test>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=test>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=test>
Message-Id: <20141220080001.D0F6B5C08ED@master.cluster>
Date: Sat, 20 Dec 2014 10:00:01 +0200 (CAT)
152.master.cluster
```

Here is my crontab entry

```
50 09 * * * PATH=/opt/torque/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:. qsub /home/test/WRF/SCRIPTS/wrf_submit_00.sh
```

and wrf_submit_00.sh has two dependent jobs to run consecutively

```
#!/bin/bash
cd WRF/WRFV3/run

FIRST =`qsub wrf_initialise.sh`
echo $FIRST
SECOND = `qsub -w depend=afterok:$FIRST wrf_00_run.sh`
echo $SECOND
exit 0
```

and the first job is

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=8:ppn=8
cd WRF/WRFV3/run
echo -n "this script is running on: "
hostname -f
date
echo ""
echo "### PBS_NODEFILE (${PBS_NODEFILE}) ###"
cat ${PBS_NODEFILE}
echo ""
mpirun ./real.exe
exit 0
```

When I submit the two jobs separately through crontab I get the same disappearance.
Please help!, am stuck. Google search of a similar problem gives me no clue.

Comment: You might want to add some additional debugging lines in you cron job. The cron environment could be different enough that your executables aren't found or other weird things. Maybe an 'echo $PATH' or 'qstat -f $FIRST' to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @chuck am trying those suggestions and others I can think of. Your indication of the path to try is very helpful

Comment: Why are you running `wrf_submit_00.sh` via `qsub`? You should probably execute it directly instead, i.e. remove `qsub` from the line in crontab.